# How to disable dates on condition in ajax calender control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ajax Calender Extender End Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081198/ajax-calender-extender-end-date)

I have 2 textboxes using ajax calender extender of ajax, 1st texbox selects start date and another(2nd) end date, now i dont want 2nd textbox to have date previous than 1st texbox. therefore want to disable those dates in 2nd calender extender. How can I do so in asp.net?